# Unable to call functions on observable results

Tags: angular, typescript, http, rxjs, typeerror

I have an interface (`Vehicle`), a class that implements it (`Car`) and has some method (`isColorRed`):

```js
export interface Vehicle{
   color : string;
}

export class Car implements Vehicle{
   color : string;
   
   constructor(obj){
      this.color = obj.color;
   }

   isColorRed(){
   return color === 'red' ? true : false;
   }
}
```

I am getting an array of `Car`s from backend and want to store only ones that are red in color:

```js
...
carsThatAreRed : Car[];
...
this.httpClient.get<Car[]>(carsUrl).pipe(
   map(cars => cars.filter(car => car.isColorRed()))
   ).subscribe(
   {
      next : (carsThatAreRed) => {
         this.carsThatAreRed = carsThatAreRed;
      }
   }
)
```

And this request fails and writes to dev console that

> `isColorRed()` is not a function

When I explicitly instantiate `Car` objects from each `Car` in the received array it works.

```js
...
.pipe(
   map(cars => cars.map(car => new Car(car)).filter(car => car.isColorRed()))
   )
...
```

Why doesn't it work without explicit mapping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a runtime error. You told TypeScript that its Cars you are getting, but at the runtime it's just plain JSON objects, with no `isColorRed` method on them, unless you explicitly convert them to Cars. Sth along these lines

```
this.httpClient.get<Vehicle[]>(carsUrl)
    .pipe(
        map((vehicles) => vehicles.map(vehicle => new Car(vehicle))), // now we made Cars
        map(cars => cars.filter(car => car.isColorRed()))
```

Comment: So there's no workaround without mapping objects to Cars first I see

Comment: @J.F.Dimdim it has to be transpiled to plain JS, so the conversion _has_ to happen. If the programmer doesn't do it explicitly, then, I guess, the only other option would be for TS to guess something. Which seems like a potentially bad idea.

Comment: OK but I still don't understand why can't typescript derive the results type. We explicitly tell it the type we want to receive in the generic `get<Cars[]>` method call. Why does it have to guess then?

Answer (score 1):

What we do in `typescript` using `as` or `<>` is called `Type assertions`.

- **Type assertions** will not covert `plain javascript object` into `custom type object`.
- **Type assertions** are hint to `compiler / IDE`
- **Type assertions** are a way to tell the compiler “trust me, I know what I’m doing.”
- **Type assertions** has no runtime impact and is used purely by the compiler.

Take a look at the compiled JavaScript and you will see the type assertion (casting) disappears because it's only for compiling

That's why IDE / Compiler is able to show suggestion `isColorRed` after `car.`

`isColorRed` is not available in response `[{plain javascript object}]`

So in-order to use `isColorRed` metod against car object,you need to instantiate `Car` object using javascript objet value.

```ts
this.httpClient
  .get<Car[]>(carsUrl)
  .pipe(map((cars) => cars.filter((car: Car) => new Car(car).isColorRed())))
  .subscribe({
    next: (carsThatAreRed) => {
      this.carsThatAreRed = carsThatAreRed;
    },
  });
```

Comment: Yeah, but if I understand correctly, generics and type assertions are different mechanisms of typescript. The problem is that `httpClient`'s get method uses type assertion inside of it and doesn't instatiate objects.